# Why does my plot look different in Shiny compared to ggplot and also different when combos are selecteD?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

This is the snippet of the ui portion of this plot:

```
tabPanel("Total Weight",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  checkboxGroupInput("workout_name", "Workout:", 
                                     c("Legs" = "Legs",
                                       "Push" = "Push",
                                       "Pull" = "Pull"))
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  plotOutput("total_weight", width = "100%"),
              )
              )
     )
```

And this is the code for the plot from the server:

```
   output$total_weight <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(df3[df3$workout_name == input$workout_name,],
            aes(x = datetime, y = total_weight)) +
                geom_point(aes(group = workout_name, colour = workout_name)) +
                geom_smooth(aes(group = workout_name, colour = workout_name), se = FALSE) +
                theme_bw() +
                labs(x = "Date",
                     y = "Weight (lbs)",
                     title = "Total Weight Lifted in Workout Sessions",
                     colour = "Workout") +
                theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face = "bold"))
     
   })
```

The plot should look like this when all options are selected:

[image: Correct Plot]

However it instead looks like this in Shiny:

[image: Incorrect]

As you can see, the values are wrong in the Shiny app. I want to be able to select which ones can be shown. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter your data frame based on an equals condition.

```
df3[df3$workout_name == input$workout_name,]
```

But the value of `input$workout_name` is a character vector so if you want all rows of the `df3` data frame where the workout name is one of the selected inputs then you should use `%in%` instead.

```
df3[df3$workout_name %in% input$workout_name, ]
```

Comment: Nice catch! Hard to find without having data or console-code.